# Twilio programmable voice - authentication with node.js using webhooks

Tags: node.js, twilio

I´m currently working on a Node.js (with Express) application using twilio voice to perform phone calls.
I want to secure the endpoints of my application using webhooks.

In twilio my phone number is configured the following way:
[image]

I want to secure the route /api/getPin using the webhook middleware provided by Twilio SDK and followed this documentation: https://www.twilio.com/docs/usage/tutorials/how-to-secure-your-express-app-by-validating-incoming-twilio-requests

My coding looks like the following (I´m storing credentials in environment variables):

```
require('dotenv').config();
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const TwilioClient = require('twilio')(process.env.TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID, process.env.TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN);
const app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));

app.post('/api/getPin', TwilioClient.webhook(), async (req, res) => {
    try {
        // Logic to get entered pin
    } catch (err) {
        res.status(500).json({success: false, message: err.message});
    }
});
```

The logic is working perfectly only when I add the authentication middleware to the route, I get the following error:

```
app.post('/api/getPin', TwilioClient.webhook(), async (req, res) => {
                                     ^

TypeError: TwilioClient.webhook is not a function
    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/www/html/twilio/server/index.js:299:38)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:831:12)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:622:3)
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

What wrong in my implementation?

Comment: Have you seen this blog? https://www.twilio.com/blog/how-to-secure-twilio-webhook-urls-in-nodejs

Comment: Yes I could use the validateRequest or webhook method. And the only difference in the blog is the bodyParser urlEncoded flag which is set to false.